# jQuery/ Javascript function says undefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, undefined

I am stuck with in a situation with no clue. I have the following code which works perfect.

```
$(document).on("click", ".connect", function (ev) {
    if()
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
    else
    {
        var item = 22;
        item = item + 1;
    }
});
```

But as soon as I remove the code inside the else statement and put it in a function, I get "item" is undefined.

```
$(document).on("click", ".connect", function (ev) {
    if()
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
    else
    {
        myFun();
    }
});
function myFun(){
    var item = 22;
    item = item + 1;
}
```

Can anybody point out the reason for this behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you take item out of any function and make it global?

Comment: That is impossible if you have what you just posted.
Please post more code - the item undefined message happens elsewhere

Comment: There's too much code hidden to actually see the problem.

Comment: The code you posted works just fine

Comment: That code will not throw such an error. Please take note of what line the error occurs on, you've left out the bit where the problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

You likely use item elsewhere.

Pass the item back to the place you need it:

```js
const myFun = function() { // define consts before using them
    var myFunItem = 22;
    myFunItem++; // always 23 by the way
    return myFunItem; // this is now available in the calling function
}; 


$(document).on("click", ".connect", function (ev) {
    if()
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
    else
    {
       var item = myFun(); 
       console.log(item); // item is 23 here
    }
});
```

Comment: The first thing that comes in mind is that, I have declared the variable elsewhere. But I have not.
It is not a question of just one variable “item”. I have 3 variables declared inside the else statement. The problem remains the same. And I know, if I declare the variable globally, it will work, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Also I don't want to pass the item back. The function itself will do the output.

Comment: You will not get an error unless you access the item in another place